# Defining an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

What does it mean 'to define an algebra'?

I have defined the four * / + - operators in n-dimensional space. Does that make it an algebra?

I'm lost, so please, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The text is at https://github.com/sjhalayka/julia_n_dimensions_paper/blob/main/julia_n.pdf

Multiplication is defined in equation 19

Division is defined in equation 27

Addition is defined in equation 18

Subtraction is defined in equation 28

Comment: This will depend on the definitions of that text.  For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field

Comment: The text is at [https://github.com/sjhalayka/julia_n_dimensions_paper/blob/main/julia_n.pdf](https://github.com/sjhalayka/julia_n_dimensions_paper/blob/main/julia_n.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematics, an algebra $A=(V,\cdot)$ over a field $K$ is a vector space $V$ equipped with a bilinear product $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$. It is enough to define this product on a basis $(e_1,\ldots ,e_n)$ of $V$ because of bilinearity. For example, let $V=\Bbb R^2$ with basis $(e_1,e_2)$ and product defined by
$$
e_1\cdot e_1=0,\; e_1\cdot e_2=e_1,\; e_2\cdot e_1=-e_1,\; e_2\cdot e_2=0.
$$
This algebra is not commutative and also not associative. But it is a Lie algebra, because the Jacobi identity holds.

Comment: Thank you so much Dietrich!